# Web platform installer remote host

Tags: shared-hosting, microsoft-web-platform

Can the web platform installer install to a remote server (e.g. shared hosting environment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Can the Microsoft Web Platform Installer install to a remote server?*  Yes, if you have Remote Desktop access to an administrative account, you can install this on a remote server.
2. *Will it work in a shared hosting environment?*  No.  However, it will work in a Virtual Private Server (VPS) environment or a "cloud" environment like Amazon's EC2.  The key is that you need to have a virtual server to yourself, and you need to be an administrator of that server.